# Jquery modal window with animation to the source place

Tags: jquery, animation, modal-dialog

I would need to find jquery modal dialog box plugin **which animates to the source place** on the parent page (from where modal was opened) **after close**.

The dialog will be opened automaticaly after page loads and I need to show user where he can find out it again after close. Any advices or suggestions how to do it or find out on the web? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you mean by 'which animates to the source place'?

Comment: You click the image placed in upper left corner for example, the modal opens and after you close it, the content should "minimalize" to the upper left corner - it should show you where is the launch button (trigger) if you would want to open it again.